# Split string column to create new binary columns

Tags: r, split, vectorization

My data has one column and I am trying to create additional columns with what’s after each “/” in the rows. Here are the first few rows of the data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  ALL = factor(c(
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off",
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov",
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov",
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cni_at.p3x.4",
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cbr_LBL"
  ))
)
```

The result should look like this (data frame) with a “1” in the new column if the variable appears in the row and “0” if not:

```
Result <- data.frame(
  ALL = factor(c(
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off",
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov",
    "/ca/put/sent_1fe. gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov",
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cni_at.p3x.4",
    "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cbr_LBL"
  )),
  ca = rep(1L, 5L),
  put = rep(1L, 5L),
  sent_1 = rep(1L, 5L),
  fe.gr = rep(1L, 5L),
  eq2_on = rep(1L, 5L),
  eq2_off = rep(1L, 5L),
  hi.on = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  hi.ov = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  cni_at.p3x.4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
  cbr_LBL = rep(0:1, c(4L, 1L))
)
```

I have tried many functions including strsplit and sapply:

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(mydata$ALL), “\\/”), “[[“, 2) #returns "ca"s only

sapply(strsplit(as.character(mydata$ALL), "\\/"), "[[", 3) #returns "put"s only
```

There are millions of rows and I’d greatly appreciate anything that is quick and efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `mtabuate` from the [**qdapTools**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapTools/index.html) package that I maintain:

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(dat[[1]]), "/"))

##   V1 ca cbr_LBL cni_at.p3x.4 eq2_off eq2_on fe.gr hi.on hi.ov put sent_1 sent_1fe.gr
## 1  1  1       0            0       1      1     1     0     0   1      1           0
## 2  1  1       0            0       1      1     1     1     1   1      1           0
## 3  1  1       0            0       1      1     0     1     1   1      0           1
## 4  1  1       0            1       1      1     1     0     0   1      1           0
## 5  1  1       1            0       1      1     1     0     0   1      1           0
```

Comment: more testing shows this answer to be fastest. Thanks Tyler!

Comment: I don't get what you mean.  They are integer values or numeric already.  which is typically what a dummy variable is.  Do you have a replacement for 0/1 that are factor equivalents?

Comment: This will put all columns equal 0 if the original value is NA. How to prevent this and get NA in output if there is a NA in input?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(mydata, "ALL", "/", type = "character", fill = 0)
#                                                ALL ALL_ca ALL_cbr_LBL
# 1              /ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off      1           0
# 2  /ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov      1           0
# 3   /ca/put/sent_1fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov      1           0
# 4 /ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cni_at.p3x.4      1           0
# 5      /ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cbr_LBL      1           1
#   ALL_cni_at.p3x.4 ALL_eq2_off ALL_eq2_on ALL_fe.gr ALL_hi.on ALL_hi.ov ALL_put
# 1                0           1          1         1         0         0       1
# 2                0           1          1         1         1         1       1
# 3                0           1          1         0         1         1       1
# 4                1           1          1         1         0         0       1
# 5                0           1          1         1         0         0       1
#   ALL_sent_1 ALL_sent_1fe.gr
# 1          1               0
# 2          1               0
# 3          0               1
# 4          1               0
# 5          1               0
```

(Note: I think there's a problem in row 3 of your `dput` which is why it doesn't match your desired output. Notice that the third item in row 3 is "sent_1fe.gr" with no "/" between them.)

Comment: Thanks, "/" is now added. "ALL_" appears in all headers of the new columns. Is there a way to prevent pasting it to each variable?

Comment: @bma92, No. That is there by design in case the user is splitting multiple columns. It shouldn't be too difficult to remove that though--just use `setnames` from "data.table" and do something like `setnames(out, gsub("ALL_", "", names(out))` (assuming you stored the output as "out"). This would then rename those columns without making copies of the data, so it is advisable to use when you are dealing with large datasets.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this

```
spt <- strsplit(as.character(mydata$ALL),"/", fixed=T)
do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(spt, factor, levels=unique(unlist(spt))), table))
```

which returns

```
       ca put sent_1 fe.gr eq2_on eq2_off hi.on hi.ov sent_1fe.gr cni_at.p3x.4 cbr_LBL
[1,] 1  1   1      1     1      1       1     0     0           0            0       0
[2,] 1  1   1      1     1      1       1     1     1           0            0       0
[3,] 1  1   1      1     0      1       1     1     1           1            0       0
[4,] 1  1   1      1     1      1       1     0     0           0            1       0
[5,] 1  1   1      1     1      1       1     0     0           0            0       1
```

Comment: This returns a list. It needs to return a data frame. Also what is faster, using this or vectorized approach?

Comment: For me it returns a matrix, bit if you need a data.frame, use `as.data.frame()` on it. If you want to know the speed, you're going to have to test it on your own data on your own computer.

Comment: as.data.frame(spt) returns "Error in data.frame(c("", "ca", "put", "sent_1", "fe.gr", "eq2_on", "eq2_off" : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 9, 8

Comment: You have to do the as.data.frame() on the result of the `do.call`

Answer (score 3):

Other option is to `melt` the `split` string in `list` to `long` form and then use `table`

```
library(reshape2)
as.data.frame.matrix(table(melt(strsplit(as.character(
                                   mydata[[1]]), "/"))[2:1]))[,-1]
#    ca eq2_off eq2_on fe.gr put sent_1 hi.on hi.ov sent_1fe.gr cni_at.p3x.4
#1  1       1      1     1   1      1     0     0           0            0
#2  1       1      1     1   1      1     1     1           0            0
#3  1       1      1     0   1      0     1     1           1            0
#4  1       1      1     1   1      1     0     0           0            1
#5  1       1      1     1   1      1     0     0           0            0
#  cbr_LBL
#1       0
#2       0
#3       0
#4       0
#5       1
```

Answer (score 2):

a `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  mutate(key = strsplit(levels(ALL)[ALL],"/"),value=1) %>%
  unnest %>%
  spread(key,value,0) %>%
  select(-rowname)

#   ALL   ca cbr_LBL cni_at.p3x.4 eq2_off eq2_on fe.gr hi.on hi.ov put sent_1
# 1   1 1  1       0            0       1      1     1     0     0   1      1
# 2   4 1  1       0            0       1      1     1     1     1   1      1
# 3   4 1  1       0            0       1      1     1     1     1   1      1
# 4   3 1  1       0            1       1      1     1     0     0   1      1
# 5   2 1  1       1            0       1      1     1     0     0   1      1
```

**data**

```
mydata <- structure(list(ALL = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c(
  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off",
  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cbr_LBL",
  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cni_at.p3x.4",
  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov"), class = "factor
  ")), .Names = "ALL", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Having myself similar, but more complex, problem I figured the following functional way that allows to cast in 'one hot' way string seperated character values of a column/s individually as well as categorical variables itself:

```
oneHotOnText <- function(datatable, columns, seperator=", "){ #argument columns is  character vector or numeric vector
  if(! "data.table" %in% .packages()) if(!require(data.table)) { install.packages("data.table"); library(data.table) }
  if(! "data.table" %in% class(datatable)) TempDT <- as.data.table(datatable) else TempDT <- copy(datatable)
  for(i in TempDT[, columns, with = F]){
    if(class(i) != "character") i <- as.character(i)
    uniqueValues <- unique(unlist(strsplit(unique(i), split=seperator)))
    if(any(uniqueValues %in% names(TempDT))) { print("Value/s of the selected column/s is/are present as variables name/s. Rename it/them.")
                                             rm(TempDT)
                                             break }
    for(j in uniqueValues) TempDT[, (j) := ifelse(grepl(j, i), 1L, 0L)]
  }
  if(exists("TempDT")) return(TempDT)
}

DF = data.frame(
  aColumn=rep(c("f", "b", "c"), 100000),
  xColumn=rep(c("N/W", "W", "R"), 100000), 
  yColumn=rep(c("A/B", "A/V", "B/G"), 100000),
  zColumn=rep(20:22, 100000))

str(DF) #factors are present in the data.frame

oneHotOnText(DF, columns = c("aColumn", "xColumn", "yColumn"), seperator="/")[] #applies the function, returns a data.table and prints the result

#        aColumn xColumn yColumn zColumn f b c N W R A B V G
#     1:       f     N/W     A/B      20 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
#     2:       b       W     A/V      21 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
#     3:       c       R     B/G      22 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
#     4:       f     N/W     A/B      20 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
#     5:       b       W     A/V      21 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
#    ---                                                    
#299996:       b       W     A/V      21 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
#299997:       c       R     B/G      22 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
#299998:       f     N/W     A/B      20 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
#299999:       b       W     A/V      21 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
#300000:       c       R     B/G      22 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Similarly it applies to the OP´s problem:

```
input <- data.frame(ALL = c("/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off",
                            "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov",
                            "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov",
                            "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cni_at.p3x.4",
                            "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cbr_LBL"
                            ))

oneHotOnText(input, columns = "ALL", seperator = "/")[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses dplyr and tidyr (note: I cleaned up what appears to be
an missing / in row three of your sample data):

```
## Input

input <- structure(
  list(ALL = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L),
       .Label = c("/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off",
                  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cbr_LBL",
                  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cni_at.p3x.4",
                  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov",
                  "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov"),
       class = "factor")),
  .Names = "ALL", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))


## Solution

require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
solution <- input  %>%
  mutate(temp = sub("^/", "", ALL)) %>%
  separate(temp,
           c("ca", "put", "sent_1", "fe.gr", "eq2_on", "eq2_off",
             "hi.on", "hi.ov", "cni_at.p3x.4", "cbr_LBL"),
           "/", extra="merge") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric(!is.na(.))), -ALL)
```

Comment: mutate_each is deprecated, mutate_at(vars(ALL), ...) might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

here is one more `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)

nn <- max(str_count(df$ALL, "/"), na.rm = T)+1

df %>% mutate(row_id =row_number()) %>%
  select(row_id, everything()) %>%
  separate(ALL, into = paste("tag", 1:nn), sep = "/") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = paste("tag", 2:nn), names_to = "name", values_to = "val") %>%
  filter(!is.na(val)) %>%
  select(-`tag 1`) %>%
  mutate(new=1) %>%
  #group_by(row_id) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = row_id, names_from = val, values_from = new, values_fill =0)


# A tibble: 5 x 11
  row_id    ca   put sent_1 fe.gr eq2_on eq2_off hi.on hi.ov cni_at.p3x.4
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1     1     1      1     1      1       1     0     0            0
2      2     1     1      1     1      1       1     1     1            0
3      3     1     1      1     1      1       1     1     1            0
4      4     1     1      1     1      1       1     0     0            1
5      5     1     1      1     1      1       1     0     0            0
# ... with 1 more variable: cbr_LBL <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiple columns with commas separate multi-items hot encoding:

```
library(qdapTools)

#hot-encoding 
mtabulate(apply(dataset[3451:3457], 1, function(x) strsplit(x, ",")))

cbind(dataset, mtabulate(strsplit(mydf$Info, ", ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(fastDummies)

dummy_cols(df, "ALL", split = "/")
```

Comment: The `qdapTools` solution appears much faster