# How to speed up the operation in R

Tags: r, performance, loops, vectorization

My data has one column and I'm trying to create additional columns with what's after each "/" in the rows. Answers to my related previous question are found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630588/split-string-in-rows-to-create-new-columns). Here are the first 5 rows of data:

```
> dput(mydata)
structure(list(ALL = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("/ca/put/
sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off",
"/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/cbr_LBL", "/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_o
n/eq2_off/cni_at.p3x.4",
"/ca/put/sent_1/fe.gr/eq2_on/eq2_off/hi.on/hi.ov"), class = "factor")), .N
ames = "ALL", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

The following works fine on the sample of 5 rows:

```
res <- strsplit(as.character(mydata$ALL),"/", fixed=T)
res.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(lapply(res, factor, levels
=unique(unlist(res))), table)))
```

But with millions of rows it's very slow...
 `system.time(replicate(75000000, res.df))` returns an error with timing stopped at `563.04 21.28 644.77`

> (Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.8Gb...):

The original data is over 400M rows and the strings between "/"s generate about 100 columns. Is there any way to speed up the above operation in R?

Comment: Try Tyler's answer from your previous question. A quick test on my system had shown his to be fastest.

Comment: Did you benchmark the answer on larger data than the test data? Since the test is very small, some solutions might scale better with larger data and become faster than your current approach.

Comment: I think the problem is not speed by that you've got out of RAM (this is what the error message basically tells you). Though, 400MM rows is definitely a huge data set for such complicated operation in R.

Comment: Why are you replicating a value, `res.df`? `replicate(75000000, res.df)` returns a matrix with 75 million columns.

Comment: Ananda, you're right...Tyler's answer is faster. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things may help speed up the creation of `res.df`. First, you don't want to be doing `unique(unlist(res))` during every iteration. Second, you should combine your functions used in `lapply` so that you only have to make single a pass over the data. You could use `Compose` from the `functional` package, but it's just as easy to write your own.

```
lvls <- unique(unlist(res))
helper <- function(x) 
{
    table(factor(x, levels=lvls))
}

res.df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(res, helper)))
```

With a data set this large, this may not solve your problem, but it's a place to start.

Answer (score -1):

If they're all slow, you do actually have an alternative; write out that column to a file, and then read it in as a delimited file, with sep = "/". Then cbind the two data.frames.

It's not particularly elegant, but.

Comment: I think you misunderstood their desired output--a binary table where the unique split values become the column names.