# creating a dummy matrix from a concatenated column

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I'm using R and I have a column that looks like this:

```
relative
aunt
mother,grandmother

sister,mother
```

My desired outcome should look like this:

```
mother  sister aunt grandmother
0       0      1    0
1       0      0    1
0       0      0    0
1       1      0    0
```

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do that using what tools?

Comment: I'm sorry about not specifying that before. I'm using R.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267552/dummy-variables-from-a-string-variable , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630588/split-string-in-rows-to-create-new-columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
relative <- c("aunt", "mother,grandmother", "sister,mother", "", "other")
R <- strsplit(relative, ',')
r <- unique(unlist(R))
result <- t(sapply(R, function(Ri) if (length(Ri)==0) rep(FALSE, length(r)) else r %in% Ri))
colnames(result) <- r
result
# > result
#       aunt mother grandmother sister other
# [1,]  TRUE  FALSE       FALSE  FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE   TRUE        TRUE  FALSE FALSE
# [3,] FALSE   TRUE       FALSE   TRUE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE  FALSE       FALSE  FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE  FALSE       FALSE  FALSE  TRUE
```

or (for integers):

```
+result
# > +result
#      aunt mother grandmother sister other
# [1,]    1      0           0      0     0
# [2,]    0      1           1      0     0
# [3,]    0      1           0      1     0
# [4,]    0      0           0      0     0
# [5,]    0      0           0      0     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked! The only problem now is that I also have in relative column the value "other": (aunt, sister, mother, grandmother, other) so when mother is true it also sees the "other" part in "mother" and puts true in "other"

Comment: and also it finds "mother" in "grandmother"

Comment: @MiladBotros I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked! I really appreciate it.