# CountVectorizer in R not fitting all the words into the bag

Tags: r, countvectorizer

I have a data frame like this:

```
    id                 words
 1:  1          capuccin,mok
 2:  2 bimboll,ext,sajonjoli
 3:  3          burrit,sincr
 4:  4  div,tir,mini,doradit
 5:  5   pan,multigran,linaz
 6:  6         tost,integral
 7:  7             pan,blanc
 8:  8  sup,pan,bco,ajonjoli
 9:  9                  wond
10: 10                  wond
```

I'm using the following codes:

```
bag_of_words <- CountVectorizer$new()
result_df <- cbind(df$id, bag_of_words$fit_transform(df$words))
```

I'd like to get something like that:

```
   tab_1$id capuccin mok bimboll ext sajonjoli...
1         1        1   1       0   0         0...
2         2        0   0       1   1         1...
3         3        0   0       0   0         0...
4       ...      ... ...     ... ...       ...
```

But, instead it returns a matrix with the number of occurrencies of every word, it's just returning with the word **wond**:

```
   df$id wond
1         1    0
2         2    0
3         3    0
4         4    0
5         5    0
6         6    0
7         7    0
8         8    0
9         9    1
10       10    1
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630588/split-string-column-to-create-new-binary-columns

Comment: Not sure how `CountVectorizer` works but the link posted above has an alternative with `mtabulate` and `strsplit` to get the same output.

Comment: With `dplyr` you can try `df %>%
 mutate(words = strsplit(words, ",")) %>%
 unnest() %>%
 count(words)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got that by using a silimar method than the suggested by [tmfmnk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5964557/tmfmnk) in the comments.

```
tab_1 <- tab_1 %>%
  unnest(words) %>%
  mutate(words = strsplit(words, ','), occ = 1) %>%
  dcast(id ~ unlist(words), fill = 0)
```

Now it's working as expected.

```
id ajonjoli bco bimboll ...
1         0   0       0 ...
2         0   0       1 ...
3         0   0       0 ...
...     ... ...     ...
```