# Split a dataframe column with a comma-separated list of tags

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr, data-cleaning

I'm dealing with a dataset of products that are characterised with tags. This is, they have a property that consists in a list of comma-separated words. For example,

```
data.frame(
   id = c(11, 12, 13),
   tags =c("wood,small,old","big,iron,artistic", "pretty,wood")
)
```

I would like to separate the tags column into different logical columns for each tag, namely

```
| id | wood | iron | small |  big |  old | artistic | pretty | 
------------------------------------------------------------
| 11 |  TRUE| FALSE|   TRUE| FALSE|  TRUE|     FALSE|   FALSE|
| 12 | FALSE|  TRUE|  FALSE|  TRUE| FALSE|      TRUE|   FALSE|
| 13 |  TRUE| FALSE|  FALSE| FALSE| FALSE|     FALSE|    TRUE|
```

I have tried to use the `separate` function from the `tidyr` package, but the tags are unordered and it is difficult to then do a column for each tag.

I have found a solution using a `mutate` from `dplyr` package and creating manually a column for each tag,

```
has_tag <- function(tag, tags) {
    strsplit(tags, ",") %>% map_lgl(function(x) tag %in% x)
}

df %>% 
    mutate(
        wood = has_tag("wood", tags),
        iron = has_tag("iron", tags),
        ...
    )
```

but new tags can appear in the future and I would like to make it scalable.

¿Is there any way to do it easily?

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/27630588/5325862

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   separate_rows(tags) %>%
    mutate(val = TRUE) %>%
    spread(tags, val, FALSE)
      id artistic   big  iron   old pretty small  wood
    1 11    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
    2 12     TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
    3 13    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

with base R it requires abit of steps:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(f~ind+values,
      cbind(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df$tags),","),df$id)),f = 1))>0)

   artistic   big  iron   old pretty small  wood
11    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
12     TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
13    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: This is very elegant!

Comment: This is just what I need. Thank you. I like so much not needing any package outside tidyverse.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape` to create a binary column, then `rename` the columns by removing the prefix

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
cSplit_e(df1, 'tags', sep=",", type = 'character', fill = 0, drop = TRUE) %>%
    mutate_at(-1, as.logical) %>%
    rename_at(-1, ~ str_remove(., 'tags_'))
#  id artistic   big  iron   old pretty small  wood
#1 11    FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#2 12     TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 13    FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE   TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

---

Or more compactly

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(df1[1],  mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1$tags), ",")))
```