# One-hot encoding a text string

Tags: r, data.table

I have a column which contains a mixed string of characters, I've created columns to represent each one of the unique characters in the string. I need to encode the columns with a `[1,0]` if any of the characters in the string matches one of these columns.

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(string = c("P_P_F_", "U_F_/", "-_P_B"),
               P = c(1,  0, 1),
               F = c(1, 1, 0),
               U = c(0, 1, 0),
               B = c(0, 0, 1))
```

In the example above `string` has the characters I need matching to the corresponding columns. The first string has a `P` and `F` so I have a `1` in those columns and a `0` in the rest.
The characters within the string are always separated by an underscore and has a maximum length of 7.

The data set is quite large so I would prefer a data.table solution is possible.

Comment: This should get you going: [Split string column to create new binary columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630588/split-string-column-to-create-new-binary-columns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mtabulate` after splitting the string

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(d, mtabulate(strsplit(d$string, "[_/-]")))
```

#### data

```
d <- data.table(string = c("P_P_F_", "U_F_/", "-_P_B"))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is about 10 seconds slower that the answer above but it is much cleaner in terms of the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Remove leading and lagging punctuations so the string is clean with only one separator between each character and then use `cSplit_e` which uses `data.table` internally.

```
library(data.table)
d = data.table(string = c("P_P_F_", "U_F_/", "-_P_B"))

d$string <- trimws(d$string, whitespace = '[[:punct:]]')
splitstackshape::cSplit_e(d, 'string', sep = '_', type = 'character', fill = 0)

#   string string_B string_F string_P string_U
#1:  P_P_F        0        1        1        0
#2:    U_F        0        1        0        1
#3:    P_B        1        0        1        0
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well but on my data set I am getting errors about can't allocate a vector of size n. My data is 2.2M rows in total

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
d[
  ,
  cbind(
    string,
    as.data.table(
      +(t(
        table(
          stack(
            setNames(
              Map(Filter, list(nchar), strsplit(string, "[_/-]")),
              seq_along(string)
            )
          )
        )
      ) > 0)
    )
  )
]
```

gives

```
   string B F P U
1: P_P_F_ 0 1 1 0
2:  U_F_/ 0 1 0 1
3:  -_P_B 1 0 1 0
```