# Transform the cell values of a column into new binary / dummy variables

Tags: r, tidyr

I've been looking through similar posts here for guidance but they all seem to focus on [splitting strings within cells into distinct columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630588/split-string-column-to-create-new-binary-columns), whereas in my data all my strings are already split into individual cells.

In other words, my data look like this:

| ID | word |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | red |
| 1 | green |
| 1 | yellow |
| 2 | blue |
| 2 | purple |
| 2 | orange |
| 2 | green |

But I want them to look like this:

| ID | blue | red | green | yellow | purple | orange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

I've tried using base R's table() to do this, but I get the error message: `Error in table(df) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements` which is strange because there are nowhere near that many elements in my dataset.

I've also tried doing this with pivot_wider(),

```
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(ID, names_from = word, values_from = word,
       values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

but running the code above gives me an error message saying that `Column 2894 must be named. Use .name_repair to specify repair.` But I don't think pivot_wider accepts .name_repair as an argument. I'm also not sure I understand why it would be necessary here since I'm just trying to create a new binary column for every unique cell value.

Any help at all is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a sample of your actual data via the `dput` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)

word = c('blue', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'blue', 'purple', 'orange', 'green')

library(data.table)

DT = data.table(ID, word)

DT

dcast(DT, ID ~ word, fill = 0L, fun.agg = \(x) ifelse(x == 0, 0, 1))
```

Output

```
   ID blue green orange purple red yellow
1:  1    1     1      0      0   1      1
2:  2    1     1      1      1   0      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fix using `mutate()` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2)
word <- c("blue", "red", "green", "yellow", "blue", "purple", "orange", "green")
dd1 <- data.frame(ID, word)

# A tibble: 2 x 7
     ID  blue   red green yellow purple orange
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1      1      0      0
2     2     1     0     1      0      1      1

dd1 %>%
  mutate(value = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = word, values_from = value, values_fill = 0)
```

This approach creates the values as a dummy variable and then `values_fill = 0` fills in the gaps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! For some reason, this solution results in the same error as mentioned above: ```Column 2894 must be named. Use .name_repair to specify repair.``` Do you have any idea how to fix this? I prefer a tidyverse solution to this problem if possible

Comment: This solution works with your minimal example. Does your data contain a NA value in the word column? If so, then that is your problem.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it doesn't seem to be the problem. Must be a data cleanliness issue. Thanks!